# ¿Cómo se puede crear un rango de timestamps?

Tags: pandas

Las operaciones para recuperar valores de objetos Serie difieren, dependiendo de si la operación se está aplicando a una serie o un DataFrame.
Sabemos que  las series, se pueden utilizar para el corte cadenas que representan fechas, cosa que no se puede hacer en los DataFrame’s (df), por ejemplo con esta senencia “rango_seleccionado["2017-12-11","2017-12-29"]”.
Tengo un DataFrame (df con las siguientes características:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 50 entries, 1 to 50
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    50 non-null object
1    50 non-null object
2    50 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
```

Lo preparo de la siguientes manera:

```
# convertir a formato fecha la columna 0    
rango_seleccionado[0] = pd.to_datetime(rango_seleccionado[0])
# Y ahora sí deberíamos poder convertirlo a numérico
rango_seleccionado[1] = pd.to_numeric(rango_seleccionado[1])
rango_seleccionado[2] = pd.to_numeric(rango_seleccionado[2])
# Modificar etiquetas columnas
rango_seleccionado.columns = ["Fecha", "Valor", "Beneficio"]    
rango_seleccionado = rango_seleccionado.set_index("Fecha")
print  ("rango_seleccionado = ", rango_seleccionado.head())
# Creamos una serie pandas 
rango_selec = rango_seleccionado["Valor"]
```

Entendiendo que en este punto he creado una Serie pandas. A continuación intento seleccionar entre dos fechas de la siguiente manera.

> rango_seleccionado["2017-12-11":"2017-12-29"]

Si en lugar de ":" pongo "," Obtengo el error:

> raise KeyError(key) KeyError: ('2018-1-26', '2018-2-1')
>   Intento a continuación ver el tipo de datos de la Serie con “rango_seleccionado.dtype()” y obtengo el error :
>
> File "F:/Python/Mi_Cartera_2/pruebas.py", line 54, in 
>       print (rango_seleccionado.dtype()) TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable
>   Con los ":", no da error, pero no selecciona nada y solamente me devuelve:

```
Series([], Name: Valor, dtype: float64)
```

Pienso que el problema puede estar en que el tipo de datos de las fechas es datetime64 y no un  DatetimeIndex. **¿Cómo puedo realizar la conversión del tipo de datos del índice?**

Comment: Prueba a usar dos puntos en lugar de coma para especificar el rango, es decir, `rango_seleccionado["2017-12-11":"2017-12-29"]`

Comment: Y para la otra cuestión, supongo que `rango_seleccionado.set_index("fecha")`, siendo`"fecha"` el nombre de la columna 0 del dataframe `rango_seleccionado`.

Answer (score 0):

He llegado a estas conclusiones. Las fechas y horas específicas en   pandas se representan utilizando pandas **Timestamp class**. Timestamp  se basa en el **dtype datetime64** de **NumPy** y tiene una precisión mayor que el objeto datetime incorporado de Python.
Las secuencias de los objetos **timestamp** se representan con pandas como objetos **DatetimeIndex**, que es un tipo de índice de pandas que está optimizado para indexar por fechas y horas. Me encontraba con dos opciones de importación. En la primera opción, importación directa de la Web "Yahoo Finances", mediante la sentencia

```
sp_500 = web.DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo", start, end)
```

obtengo un df que establece como índice la columna de las fechas, denominada "Date". Construye lo que se denomina un DatetimeIndex. 
La opción 2 consistía en una importación desde un fihero .xlsx ó bien .csv. con la siguiente sentencia.

> sp500_1 = pd.read_csv("sp_500.csv", index_col="Date")

En este caso el índice no es un DatetimeIndex. y su formato es datetime
Dado que tengo que importar de este tipo de ficheros, utilizo una Opción 3,  consistente en importar todas las columnas, dejando que pandas asigne números al índice de forma automática. A continuación convierto la columna "Date" al formato  dtype datetime64   y seguidamente la convierto en índice.
Para solucionar el problema de la opción 2, lo que hago es importar sin preestablecer el índice. A continuación convierto el tipo de datos de la columna “Date”  al tipo datetime64:

> sp500_1 = pd.read_csv("sp_500.csv", index_col=False, usecols=[0, 2, 3,
>   6]) df['datos'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datos'])

y seguidamente establezco esta columna como índice

> df.index = df['datos] del df['date']

De esta manera puedo aprovechar toda la funcionalidad de **Timestamp class**, que era mi problema inicial.